# Error while building with webpack

Tags: javascript, android, webpack, nativescript

I am having a problem with the build, I made a simple app with 2 pages and one component it runs ok but when I build (tns build android --bundle), I have this errors message:

```
ERROR in ./views/sign-up/list-page.xml
Module not found: Error: Can''t resolve 'D:devmobiletestappsharedcomponentsmenu.xml' in 'D:\dev\mobile\test\app\views\list'
 @ ./views/list/list-page.xml 1:360-425 1:498-563
 @ . sync (root|page)\.(xml|css|js|ts|scss)$
 @ ../node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/register-modules.js
 @ ./app.js

ERROR in ./views/home/home-page.xml
Module not found: Error: Can''t resolve 'D:devmobiletestappsharedcomponentsmenu.xml' in 'D:\dev\mobile\test\app\views\home'
 @ ./views/home/home-page.xml 1:360-425 1:498-563
 @ . sync (root|page)\.(xml|css|js|ts|scss)$
 @ ../node_modules/nativescript-dev-webpack/register-modules.js
 @ ./app.js
```

My component

```
<StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
    <Button text="A" class="btn btn-rounded-lg btn-active btn-outline" width="25%"></Button>
    <Button text="B" class="btn btn-rounded-lg btn-active btn-outline" width="25%"></Button>
    <Button text="C" class="btn btn-rounded-lg btn-active btn-outline" width="25%"></Button>
</StackLayout>
```

My pages XML

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" 
    xmlns:components="shared/components" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" class="page" actionBarHidden="true">
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the the same issue with latest nativescript-dev-webpack, what I've found is that if all the pages are in root folder with their name ending in "page" then its working.

Answer (score 0):

Update to     `"nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.13.0",`
(& npm install and clean platform  )

We've discussed about it here  :  https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-webpack/issues/559#issuecomment-396279840

This has been solved.

Comment: It didn't worked, the comands I used: npm install nativescript-dev-webpack@0.13.0 ### tns platform remove android ### tns platform add android ### node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs